# Batch file that finds applications, not processes, in Task Manager

Tags: batch-file, taskmanager

I have a question about a batch process that I haven't been able to find anywhere yet. I need to create a batch file that determines whether a task under the applications in Task Manager is running and take a certain action. I found a lot of answers on how to tell whether a process is running, but this case is a little trickier. The applications task contains the text

*Administrator: [YODA][oo.server.start]*

but the process in the Task Manager is listed only as *cmd.exe* which is unfortunately not specific enough to know whether it's the task I want. I've tried using psexec, but none of the information it's given me has been helpful. And as far as I'm aware, there's no way to find the tasks running (not the processes) in cmd. Any thoughts?

Comment: TaskMgr.exe's "Applications" seem to correspond to open windows. I don't know of any native utilities that deal with windows. We use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) for this purpose. It is possible to build console applications with it that can deal with window titles and processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How about PowerShell?

```
Get-Process | Select-Object MainWindowTitle
```

Use it in batch something like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('"PowerShell Get-Process ^| Select-Object MainWindowTitle ^| Select-String YODA"') do echo(%%A
```

Example Output:

```
@{MainWindowTitle=Administrator:  YODA}
```

---

#### No PowerShell...

If you know the **exact** title of the application you can use `tasklist`

```
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:  YODA"
```

Note that there are two spaces between `Administrator:` and `YODA` because cmd.exe has that quirk.

Example Output:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
cmd.exe                       5996 Console                    1      1,024 K
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to use regex? The Administrator: [YODA][oo.server.start] part is followed by a time stamp so I'd like to find any application with that first part followed by anything else in the title

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `title` command in the batch file to set the title and then use `tasklist` to determine the window with that title.

Comment: I ended up using a variant of findstr which worked but thanks for this post too